# C - Why does this loop repeat, even when the right input is given to break it, using getchar()?

Tags: c, validation, input, while-loop, getchar

(New to C and programming in general.)

When I run this small program to prompt a user to enter 1 or 2, I want to check if the input is correct, so I ran a while loop that was supposed to run until the correct input is given. But even when I type 1 or 2 (doesn't matter whether it's from the beginning or after giving invalid input), the error message keeps printing.

Am I supposed to have a break in the while loop? If so, is there a more efficient/"less code" way of checking user input?

```
int main(void) {

char c;

printf("Press '1' or Press '2': ");
c = getchar();
while ((c != '1') || (c != '2')) {
    printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Please try again: ");
    c = getchar();
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the code and pretend `c=1`. It becomes "While false or true"

Comment: I do not think you have a code issue. I think you have a logic issue. The computer is doing exactly what you told it to

Comment: [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is worth a read.

Comment: I make this mistake all the time, unfortunately. It's the && vs ||, as others have mentioned. I appreciate all the help, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`. Think: if I enter 1, then `(1 != 1)` is `false`, but `(1 != 2)` is `true`, then `(false || true) == true`. Using `&&` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
(c != '1') && (c != '2')
```

This will be the right condition.

Also `int c`; `getchar()` returns `int`.

In words your condition was `while( c is not '1' OR c is not '2' ) keep looping`.

For `c='1'` or `c='2'` one of the condition would be true. Making it loop again and again.

Btw the expression (`a||b`) would be true if these holds

```
a   b   a||b
--+---+-------
F   F     F
T   F     T
F   T     T
T   T     T         T:True F:False
```